# Neovim Markdown toggling bold keybind

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, filetype-markdown

I am trying to make it so I can have a **keymap** for toggling things like **bold** in a **markdown** file.
I used to use **vscode** with the **markdown** plugin and they offered the option to, with a simple keybind, toggle on or off the **bold** on a specific word by adding two asterisks on each side of the word. If the cursor wasn't on top of a word, the four asterisks would be written and the cursor placed inside ready to write what I would like in bold.

In **neovim** I didn't find any plugin with this capability so I just thought about writing my own keybind for that.

The problem I found was detecting if the word was already with bold active or not. I could make two different keymaps, but wouldn't be what I was looking for.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use surround.vim for this. You could do

```
nmap <buffer> <your keys> ysiw*
nmap <buffer> <more keys> ds*
```

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` or equivalent. Make sure to adjust `b:undo_ftplugin`.